# Jquery toggleslide with button

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, show

I have div of red box that shows text where it said "hello world", there is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#box).contents().length == 0))
$('#box').hide();
else
$('#box').show();
    }
});
```

what does do is that if this box is not empty, then it will show box, if this red box is empty, then it will not show it. 
this jquery works great.

And now I want to add toggleslider in same box "id="box", and I used this jquery code ..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

the problem is that is not working because is crashed with first jquery codes. 
is only works fine one of those, can't have both same time.

the only way that might works is to merge together, what i like to have is when load the page, if red box is not empty, then show red box, if empty then not show box while have options for user to click button to slide up and down of that red box.

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alidad3250/kut9vxfq/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had quite some syntax errors there ... 
Fort example have a look at this: `$('#box).contents().length`.
You did not close the quotes in the separator. It should be:
`$('#box').contents().length`.

Here is a working fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('#box').contents().length == 0){
$('#box').hide();
} else {
$('#box').show();
}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#box{
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">Hello World</div>

<div id="click">
click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($('#box').contents().length == 0){
        $('#box').hide();
    }else{
        $('#box').show();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $("#box").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#box{
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="box">Hello World</div>
<div id="click">click me</div>
```